# How to deserialize csv based on line format

Tags: csv, rust, serde

I have a csv without headers that can have lines in these three following formats:

char,int,int,string,int

char,int,string

char

The first character defines the format and be one of the values (A,B,C) respectively. Does anyone know a way to deserialize it based on the line format?

Comment: What have you tried, etc

Comment: Hm, I'm curious how to best realize that. The [naive approach](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fff8385efd974572636a0380c30daf46) doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep it simple. You can always parse it manually.

```rust
use std::io::{self, BufRead, Error, ErrorKind};

pub enum CsvLine {
    A(i32, i32, String, i32),
    B(i32, String),
    C,
}

pub fn read_lines<R: BufRead>(reader: &mut R) -> io::Result<Vec<CsvLine>> {
    let mut lines = Vec::new();

    for line in reader.lines() {
        let line = line?;

        let trimmed = line.trim();
        if trimmed.is_empty() {
            continue
        }
        
        // Split line by commas 
        let items: Vec<&str> = trimmed.split(',').collect();
        
        match items[0] {
            "A" => {
                lines.push(CsvLine::A (
                    items[1].parse::<i32>().map_err(|e| Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, e))?,
                    items[2].parse::<i32>().map_err(|e| Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, e))?,
                    items[3].to_string(),
                    items[4].parse::<i32>().map_err(|e| Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, e))?,
                ));
            }
            "B" => {
                lines.push(CsvLine::B (
                    items[1].parse::<i32>().map_err(|e| Error::new(ErrorKind::Other, e))?,
                    items[2].to_string(),
                ));
            }
            "C" => lines.push(CsvLine::C),
            x => panic!("Unexpected string {:?} in first column!", x),
        }
    }
    
    Ok(lines)
}
```

Calling this function would look something like this:

```rust
let mut file = File::open("path/to/data.csv").unwrap();
let mut reader = BufReader::new(file);

let lines: Vec<CsvLine> = read_lines(&mut reader).unwrap();
```

But you may want to keep in mind that I didn't bother to handle a couple edge cases. It may panic if there are not enough items to satisfy the requirements and it makes no attempt to parse more complex strings. For example, `"\"quoted strings\""` and `"\"string, with, commas\""` would likely cause issues.